# Invalid and/or missing SSL certificate

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, stocktwits

I'm trying to build a datastore on Google App Engine to collect some stream data off of StockTwits for a bunch of companies. I'm basically replicating one I did with Twitter, but it's giving me an HTTPException: Invalid and/or missing SSL certificate error for one of the URLs. I changed the URL to look at another company, but got the same result.

Here's the code that pulls the data:

```
class StreamHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

def get(self):

    tickers = ['AAPL','GOOG', 'IBM', 'BAC', 'INTC',
               'DELL', 'C', 'JPM', 'WFM', 'WMT', 
               'AMZN', 'HOT', 'SPG', 'SWY', 'HTSI', 
               'DUK', 'CEG', 'XOM', 'F', 'WFC', 
               'CSCO', 'UAL', 'LUV', 'DAL', 'COST', 'YUM',
               'TLT', 'HYG', 'JNK', 'LQD', 'MSFT',
               'GE', 'LVS', 'MGM', 'TWX', 'DIS', 'CMCSA',
               'TWC', 'ORCL', 'WPO', 'NYT', 'GM', 'JCP', 
               'LNKD', 'OPEN', 'NFLX', 'SBUX', 'GMCR', 
               'SPLS', 'BBY', 'BBBY', 'YHOO', 'MAR', 
               'L', 'LOW', 'HD', 'HOV', 'TOL', 'NVR', 'RYL', 
               'GIS', 'K', 'POST', 'KRFT', 'CHK', 'GGP', 
               'RSE', 'RWT', 'AIG', 'CB', 'BRK.A', 'CAT']

    for i in set(tickers):

        urlst = 'https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/streams/symbol/'
        tickerstringst = urlst + i + '.json'
        tickurlst = urllib2.Request(tickerstringst)
        sttweets = urllib2.urlopen(tickurlst)
        stcode = sttweets.getcode()

        if stcode == 200:
            stresults = json.load(sttweets, 'utf-8')
            if "messages" in stresults:
                stentries = stresults["messages"]
                for stentry in stentries:
                    sttweet = streamdata()
                    stcreated = stentry['created_at']
                    sttweetid = str(stentry['id'])
                    sttweettxt = stentry['body']
                    sttweet.ticker = i
                    sttweet.created_at = stcreated
                    sttweet.tweet_id = sttweetid
                    sttweet.text = sttweettxt
                    sttweet.source = "StockTwits"
                    sttweet.put()
```

And here's the log file that shows the error. I'm running this on the local Python development server, btw:

```
WARNING  2012-12-06 23:20:12,993 dev_appserver.py:3655] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module. ImportError: No module named _imaging
INFO     2012-12-06 23:20:13,017 dev_appserver_multiprocess.py:655] Running application dev~jibdantestv2 on port 8088: http://localhost:8088
INFO     2012-12-06 23:20:13,017 dev_appserver_multiprocess.py:657] Admin console is available at: http://localhost:8088/_ah/admin   
INFO     2012-12-06 23:20:54,776 dev_appserver.py:3092] "GET /_ah/admin HTTP/1.1" 302 -
INFO     2012-12-06 23:20:54,953 dev_appserver.py:3092] "GET /_ah/admin/datastore HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2012-12-06 23:20:55,280 dev_appserver.py:3092] "GET /_ah/admin/images/google.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2012-12-06 23:21:04,617 dev_appserver.py:3092] "GET /_ah/admin/cron HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2012-12-06 23:21:04,815 dev_appserver.py:3092] "GET /_ah/admin/images/google.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 -
WARNING  2012-12-06 23:21:07,392 urlfetch_stub.py:448] Stripped prohibited headers from URLFetch request: ['Host']
ERROR    2012-12-06 23:21:09,921 webapp2.py:1553] Invalid and/or missing SSL certificate for URL: https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/streams/symbol/GIS.json
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1536, in __call__
rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1530, in __call__
rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
return handler.dispatch()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Tank\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\jibdantestv2\main.py", line 38, in get
sttweets = urllib2.urlopen(tickurlst)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 400, in open
response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 418, in _open
'_open', req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1215, in https_open
return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1180, in do_open
r = h.getresponse(buffering=True)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\dist27\httplib.py", line 502, in getresponse
raise HTTPException(str(e))
HTTPException: Invalid and/or missing SSL certificate for URL: https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/streams/symbol/GIS.json
INFO     2012-12-06 23:21:09,937 dev_appserver.py:3092] "GET /add_data HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Comment: I don't know why GAE is having a problem with it, but I notice the server name doesn't match the certificate Common Name, only one of it's Subject Alternative Names. (Also wget complains about this.) Google Chrome browser shows a green lock on the page, is it's happy with the cert.

Comment: Hi Jim, if you're talking about the server name (http://localhost:8088), that's the address on my local machine where I'm running the App Engine SDK. The URL that throws off the error is the URL that I'm accessing via the StockTwits REST API. So I'm running a test to see if I can do a GET request and put the data into a local instance of Google's App Engine datastore.

Comment: No, I was referring to https://api.stocktwits.com. The certificate's Subject is ssl2361.cloudflare.com and "Subject Alternative Name" contains "DNS Name=*.stocktwits.com" (as one entry in a long list). This is unusual, but probably based on some standard that browsers follow. I'm wondering if the GAE API you're using just doesn't support it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know why GAE is having a problem with it, but I notice the certificate returned by api.stocktwits.com doesn't match the server name on its Subject's Common Name (which is ssl2361.cloudflare.com), but only on one of its Subject Alternative Names ("DNS Name=*.stocktwits.com"). Maybe Subject Alternatives Names are not supported, or don't work with wildcard names as used here. (This would be a Google bug / missing feature.)

I was able to reproduce your problem and find a workaround by calling GAE urlfetch.fetch API. (As you may know, on GAE urllib2 is implemented as a wrapper for urlfetch.)

Starting at the line with your `urllib2.Request` up to your `jason.load`, replace with:

```
sttweets = urlfetch.fetch(tickerstringst, validate_certificate=False)
stcode = sttweets.status_code

if stcode == 200:
    stresults = json.loads(sttweets.content, 'utf-8')
```

And your error goes away, along with any assurance you are actually taking with the real site (though the traffic should still be encrypted).

Currently the `urlfetch.fetch` GAE API docs say:

> `validate_certificate`
>   The underlying implementation currently defaults to False, but will default to True in the near future.

Well, welcome to the future because validate_certificate now seems to be defaulting to `True`.

This is probably a bug (or missing feature, if you want to be kind) in GAE urlfetch.fetch and I encourage you to report it to Google as such.

Comment: Winner winner chicken dinner! Jim, just wanted to let you know that the code is working. The issue you cited notwithstanding, I'm in good shape. But since this is just a prototype I'm looking to build, I'm ok with that.

Comment: This is still a problem with a GAE dev server downloaded today (go_appengine_sdk_darwin_amd64-1.9.30.zip).

Comment: I still have this problem, GAE cannot even validate google servers: `import urllib2; urllib2.urlopen("https://talkgadget.google.com/talkgadget/channel.js")`

Comment: @speedplane, I hope the (4 year old) workaround is still working. You can post a bug report to Google for this. Even if urlfetch.fetch(, validate_certificate=False) still works, it's not a total fix. It opens up the possibility of a man-in-the-middle attack with either doesn't matter or could be VERY BAD.

Comment: @jimhark It's pointless, Google ignores their bug reports. This is only happening on the development server with windows, so I can work around it for now.

Comment: Whoah, please do not disable certificate validation. This answer is bad advice.

Comment: @ashgromnies, what's your solution? While it would be bad advice to suggest it's okay to connect to your financial institution or perform a financial transaction with a merchant without validation, that's not what the OP is doing. It's pointed out that there is no assurance the connection is to the intended site. The user can decide if this is appropriate for their situation. Requirement for validation depends on context, an absolute prohibition is overkill, especially if you can't provide a better fix. (This issue is 4 years old, perhaps Google has fixed it by now.)

Comment: @jimhark - I've ran into this issue today while trying to connect to *.google.com while on OSX. Sad to say it's still a problem 4 years on.

Comment: The recent issue is due to the included pinned certificates distributed with the Google App Engine SDK being out-of-date. You can fix it by temporarily disabling pinning (not validation entirely!) by moving away the two files: 

google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/cacerts/cacerts.txt
google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/cacerts/urlfetch_cacerts.txt

Answer (score -1):

I'm not too familiar with GAE, so that could be an issue with accessing the API end-points. Also, could be that you're not using right Python library to do SSL requests, but since you said you're using the same code for Twitter requests, maybe that's not the case.

Could you try using the same code locally or another server, not GAE?

Comment: Sayem, thanks. I've actually run this a number of times locally right from the Python command line prompt. But if I can't get a workaround working, it does give me an idea for a plan B to fall back to. Just won't be as clean as the original plan :\

Comment: Ok cool, then it must be something with GAE then. Glad you at least have it working locally.